# How to do Redirection in a new tab with 'POST' using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, redirect

Any how I managed to find a jquery plugin which redirects with 'POST'. But It's getting open in same window. I want it in a new tab. Please help me out guys.

Here is my code of jquery which redirects

```
 $().redirect('DLE_Report.php', {'Partner_Id': Partner_Id, 'Project_Id': Project_Id, 'Proposal_Id': Proposal_Id, 'Version_Id': Version_Id});
```

I used *jquery.redirect.min.js* plugin for redirection.

Please Remember, I want to redirect with 'POST' method. Every one here answered for GET method.

Answer (score 10):

You need to open `url` in a new tab using `window.open()` function.

**Js:**

```
  function OpenInNewTab(url )
{
  var win=window.open("http://www.google.com", '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

**Html:**

```
<div onclick="OpenInNewTab();">Something To Click On</div>
```

[**Function Refrence**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

[**Similar Question Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to open in a new tab, not redirect. Or it wouldn't mean redirect!

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/open-link-in-new-tab-with-click

Answer (score 0):

```
this code helpful for you.

<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_newtab">click</a>
```